# PostgreSQL reset a sequence

Tags: postgresql

I try to set my start increment value but I "get relation does not exist". I have a table named student and a column named student_id.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE student_student_id_seq RESTART WITH 18354001
```

I tried to use double and single quotes but it does not work.

I know that is simple and so general question but I could not handle it.

Comment: Can you show the table definition, please? Are you sure that's what the sequence is named, or did you just derive it from (current) table+column name?

Comment: Did you check SELECT * FROM pg_sequences; to get the correct name?

Comment: Also in `psql` show output of `show search_path;`

Comment: @Bergi as you said, I derived it by the formula

Comment: @FrankHeikens it worked, thank you. I can mark as answer if you push it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sequence associated to a given table/column using

```sql
select pg_get_serial_sequence('myschema.mytable','mycolumn');
```

Comment: Someone solved the problem but also I could not run pg_get_serial_sequence function.